# Python Uniform distribution of points on 4 dimensional sphere

Tags: python, distribution, trigonometry, montecarlo, polar-coordinates

I need a uniform distribution of points on a 4 dimensional sphere. I know this is not as trivial as picking 3 angles and using polar coordinates.

In 3 dimensions I use

```
from random import random

u=random()
costheta = 2*u -1 #for distribution between -1 and 1
theta = acos(costheta)
phi = 2*pi*random

x=costheta
y=sin(theta)*cos(phi)
x=sin(theta)*sin(phi)
```

This gives a uniform distribution of x, y and z.

How can I obtain a similar distribution for 4 dimensions?

Comment: How to generate uniformly distributed points at random on an N-sphere: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Uniformly_at_random_from_the_.28n.C2.A0.E2.88.92.C2.A01.29-sphere

Comment: wait, you want the points to be on a sphere, but uniformly distributed in x,y,z,(4th dimension)? that doesn't add up for me. I don't think that points uniformly distributed on a sphere would map to uniformly distributed in 4-space.

Comment: @SchighSchagh so you can't run monte carlo simulations in 4 dimensions?

Comment: @SameerPatel This doesn't have anything to do with Monte Carlo or any other sampling method. There are two different spaces here, (one is R^4, the other is the surface of the 4-sphere), and we need to know with respect to which you want to have a uniformly-at-random distribution.

Answer (score 11):

[A standard way](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7984/842), though, perhaps [not the fastest](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177692644), is to use Muller's method to generate uniformly distributed points on an N-sphere:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d

N = 600
dim = 3

norm = np.random.normal
normal_deviates = norm(size=(dim, N))

radius = np.sqrt((normal_deviates**2).sum(axis=0))
points = normal_deviates/radius

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))
ax.scatter(*points)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Simply change `dim = 3` to `dim = 4` to generate points on a 4-sphere.

Comment: Taking a uniform distribution would yield a sphere sampled with a density of points that is higher towards the corners of the cube it would occupy. How to prove that using a Gaussian distribution wouldn't cause this problem, too? It seems plausible if I picture it mentally, but is it really, and why? I assume numpy's Gaussian distributions to be independent for each coordinate when specifying a size.

Comment: And what about divisions by zero?

Comment: @GuillaumeChevalier: I confess I do not understand the details, but perhaps you will find [this proof outline useful](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7977/how-to-generate-uniformly-distributed-points-on-the-surface-of-the-3-d-unit-sphe#comment13055_7984). On the issue of division by zero: I believe the probability of the divisor being 0 is itself 0. On a practical level, NumPy handles division by zero by issuing a *warning* and returning `NaN` (and Matplotlib skips points equal to NaN).

Comment: That's a great proof! Thanks.

Comment: how could we write `points` to a txt file? i used `np.savetxt('sphere.csv', points, delimiter=',')` but it saves them as three big rows instead of 3 columns

Comment: Greate solution, but how to change the center of the sphere and maximum radius?

Comment: @user3379482: You can shift `points` to a new location and with a new radius by using `points = new_radius * points + new_location`, where `new_radius` is a scalar, and `new_location` is a sequence (such as a tuple, list, or NumPy array).

Answer (score 2):

Take a point in 4D space whose coordinates are distributed normally, and calculate its unit vector. This will be on the unit 4-sphere.

```
from random import random
import math
x=random.normalvariate(0,1)
y=random.normalvariate(0,1)
z=random.normalvariate(0,1)
w=random.normalvariate(0,1)
r=math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z + w*w)
x/=r
y/=r
z/=r
w/=r
print (x,y,z,w)
```

Comment: Sure, this will generate a random point on a 4-sphere, but is the distribution uniform?

Comment: @SchighSchagh: Uniformly distributed? Yes.

Comment: x,y,z,w are initially uniformly at random with respect to R^4, but then they undergo a non-linear transform, and it's still not clear to me if OP wants uniformly at random with respect to the surface of the sphere or with respect to R^4. EDIT: can you specify with respect to what you claim uniformly at random, and prove it?

Comment: @SchighSchagh: Oops, I forgot to normally distribute them. See http://enwp.org/N-sphere#Uniformly_at_random_from_the_.28n.C2.A0.E2.88.92.C2.A01.29-sphere.

Comment: What about divisions by zero?

Answer (score 1):

I like @unutbu's answer if the gaussian sampling really creates an evenly spaced spherical distribution (unlike sampling from a cube), but to avoid sampling on a Gaussian distribution and to have to prove that, there is a simple solution: to **sample on a uniform distribution on a sphere** (not on a cube).

1. Generate points on a **uniform distribution**.
2. Compute the **squared radius** of each point (avoid the square root).
3. **Discard points**:

   - Discard points for which the squared radius is greater than 1 (thus, for which the unsquared radius is greater than 1).
   - Discard points too close to a radius of zero to avoid numerical instabilities related to the division in the next step.
4. For each sampled point kept, **divide the sampled point by the norm** so as to renormalize it the unit radius.
5. **Wash and repeat** for more points because of discarded samples.

This obviously works in an n-dimensional space, since the radius is always the L2-norm in higher dimensions.

It is fast so as avoiding a square-root and sampling on a Gaussian distribution, but it's not a vectorized algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good [solution](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2016/04/06/generate-points-uniformly-in-ball.html) for sampling from N-dim sphere. The main idea is:

**If Y is drawn from the uncorrelated multivariate normal distribution, then *S = Y / ||Y||* has the uniform distribution on the unit d-sphere. Multiplying S by *U<sup>1/d</sup>*, where U has the uniform distribution on the unit interval (0,1), creates the uniform distribution in the unit d-dimensional ball.**

Here is the python code to do this:

```
Y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=[0], cov=np.eye(1,1), size=(n_dims, n_samples))
Y = np.squeeze(Y, -1)
Y /= np.sqrt(np.sum(Y * sample_isotropic, axis=0))
U = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(n_samples)) ** (1/n_dims)
Y *= distr * radius # in my case radius is one
```

This is what I get for the sphere:

[image: sphere]

Comment: What are the variables `distr` and `sample_isotropic`? Could you modify the code example so that it works?

Comment: How is this conceptually different from unutbu's answer? Why do you generate `U` but not use it?